# Google geocoder status is OVER_QUERY_LIMIT Lightning Map

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, map, google-map

I have an aura lightning component that uses Lightning:Map. When i have more than 10 addresses, i get the message Google geocoder status is OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.

- 1) Are there any limits on how many addresses we can query? How could
  we overcome this?
- 2) Are there any limitations related to how many times this component
  will be called ? For example, i use this component in my home page.
  And many users are going to refresh and use the page. Is there a
  chance that after a number of loads/refreshes, the component will
  stop displaying or an error to be caused?

I thought lightning map did not have any limits at all and i could use it in my lightning components for multiple addresses as well as to use them and load/refresh them as many times as we want, without considering any limits. Could please someone help me by giving me the right information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `lightning:map` documentation, under [Usage Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:map/documentation), emphasis mine:

> The lightning:map component relies on data from Google for geocoding and mapping imagery. Inaccuracies or geocoding errors in the data can't be fixed by Salesforce.
>
> **You can specify a maximum of 10 geocoded address lookups per map**. Lookups for both the mapMarkers and center attributes count toward this limit. To display more markers, provide location values using a pair of latitude and longitude coordinates, which don't require geocoding. Address locations that exceed the geocoding limit are ignored.
>
> We recommend limiting your map to 100 locations in total. For example, if you provide map markers for 5 geocoded addresses, you can provide up to 95 additional markers using latitude and longitude.

So, while this error message itself [usually indicates you've exceeded the daily quota from Google Maps or your requests are being throttled](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits), in this case it looks like an imposed limitation by Salesforce. You're going to have to limit yourself to 10 geocoded address or fewer.

I don't see any limitations to number of times a user can load a `lightning:map` component though, so unless someone can point to documentation that says otherwise, I don't believe there are limits to views.